# How to get unique records from duplicated records (by ignoring first two characters)?

Tags: mysql, sql

How could we get a list of unique userId from below table (10 records)?

Here is the rule: When comparing userId, only search userId starting with 'AB' and its matching duplicates (except 'AB'). Then get a list of "unique userId" by only returning above duplicated userId that is not having 'AB' at the beginning.

I know it sounds confusing, please see example below:

Table **UserName** with ten records, and its **userId** fields (10 records) are:

```
ABC1234
C1234
C12345
BC12345
BBC1234

ABF1235
F1235

BCD3456
D3456

DE3456
```

Desired Result:

```
C1234
F1235
```

I used some query below but found it didn't resolve the problem at all. This issue is much more complicated than I thought because I don't know how to make sure I only find userIds starting with 'AB' and its duplicates (but without 'AB' at the beginning).

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LEFT(userId, 2) IN ('AB') THEN SUBSTRING(userId, 3)
                    ELSE userId
               END) AS co_count, userId
FROM UserName c where userId like 'AB%';
```

Thanks for any help or hint!

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: The purpose of this question is to purge some old data in system (I agree there might be some poor design). I know it's a hard SQL question. My  concern now is if this task is simply not doable with SQL statements. Then I might have to change to a Java program for this purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your result seems you are just lokoking for the left of the string startin with 'AB' without 'AB'

```
SELECT distinct  substr(userId , -(length(userID)-2))
from  UserName 
where userId like 'AB%';
```

for include alos the rows that not start with 'AB' you could use a UNION

```
SELECT substr(userId , -(length(userID)-2))
from  UserName 
where userId like 'AB%'
UNION 
SELECT userId 
from  UserName 
where userId NOYT like 'AB%'
```

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge You are right, my query was not working at all because it didn't consider the duplicate record that doesn't start with 'AB'. i.e. I need to find out duplicated records first: ABC1234 and C1234, then get C1234 as output. Shall I use join statements to include in C1234? Thanks.

Comment: your comment is not clear to me .  .. my answer  return  the valexpected  result you posted in question  ?? ..  anyway i have add a suggestion  ..  for userID not starting with 'AB'

Comment: Thank you @scaisEdge, your solution is very smart. I understand it now, you were right. It solved 99% of my question. Thanks.  

My only outstanding question is your query is not going to check if there is any duplicate at the beginning,  i.e. when there is only one record ABC1234 (let's suppose there is no duplicated record of C1234 in the table), i want the output is nothing (0 record since there is no duplicated record). But your query will return C1234 no matter what. I'm not sure if i'm asking too much, but do you think it very hard to resolve this last 1%? Any hint? Thx again. 
C1234